# How to install jQuery Intellisense(jQuery-vsdoc) in ASP.net Core

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm trying to install `jQuery-vsdoc` in an ASP.net Core project so I can see jQuery Intellisense, but the intellisense isn't showing up; what do I need to do?

I've tried with bower: `bower install jquery-vsdoc` but I get this error:

> ENOTFOUND Package JQuery-vsdoc not found

I have created a new MVC project and copied the `jquery-2.1.0-vsdoc` file generated and added a reference to it from the `_Layout` page but nothing happens neither.

What do I need to do to have Intellisense for jQuery working in ASP.net Core? Is there any way that I can install it with bower? (I know bower is made to install client-side packages)...

Comment: you don't have to use vsdoc, just add this at the top of your javascript file
`/// <reference path="..\path\to\jquery-2.2.4.js" />` change only path and your jquery version

Answer (score 0):

You can right-click on the project, click add and you will see the option for _reference.js file as outlined here:  [Add the reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37514269/javascript-intellisense-in-empty-asp-net-core-project)